# How can I understand and resolve helm chart errors?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, rasa, rasa-x

I get the following error message when trying to install the rasa x helm chart:

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1
```

Is there anyone who can help me understand this error message?

These are the commands I use in the terminal:

```
helm repo add rasa-x https://rasahq.github.io/rasa-x-helm

kubectl create namespace my-namespace

helm --namespace my-namespace install --values values.yml my-release rasa-x/rasa-x
```

In my values.yaml I have:

```
nginx:
  service:
    # connect LoadBalancer directly to VMs' internal IP
    # You get this value with: $ hostname -I
    externalIPs: [10.164.0.2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart you are using tries to create an Ingress object, using an API version that was deprecated a while ago, and is no longer recognized.

Issue comes from there: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa-x-helm/blob/main/charts/rasa-x/templates/ingress.yaml#L4-L10

For some reason, Helm doesn't detect the proper API version (.Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version). Though having worked on other charts, capabilites discovery isn't 100% reliable - eg. using ArgoCD.

As a workaround, you could try to generate objects into a file:

```
helm --dry-run [your-options] >my-rendered-chart.yaml
sed -i 's|extensions/v1beta1|networking.k8s.io/v1|' my-rendered-chart.yaml
kubectl apply -f my-rendered-chart.yaml
```

Although this kinda defeats the purpose of Helm. It would be best to figure out a fix and contribute it.

To work on a chart, you could extract it locally, using.

```
helm repo add rasahq  https://rasahq.github.io/rasa-x-helm 
helm fetch rasahq/rasa-x --untar
ls rasa-x/
```

You could then work on a patch, testing your changes with:

```
helm install --dry-run --debug ./my-chart
helm install --dry-run --debug ./my-chart | kubectl apply -f-
...
```

Comment: Thank you @SYN! I'm going to try your solution!

Comment: I did `helm fetch https://rasahq.github.io/rasa-x-helm --untar` and then I got a `my-rendered-chart.yaml`. Only problem is that `my-rendered-chart.yaml` is an empty .yaml file. Or should it supposed to be empty?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the commands for that chart. Basically: you shouldn't fetch an URL. Just use the name you would pass to helm install

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I'm going to debug.